# need to change values of json file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to change values of JSON file using sed,

I saw a lot of people suggesting using jq, python, or Perl.

But I'm working inside a container and I want it to be as simple as possible so only sed is the needed solution for me.

the JSON file is:

```
{
  "useCaseName" : "rca",
  "algorithm" : "log-clustering-train",
  "mainClass" : "com.hp.analytics.logclustering.MainTrainer",
  "applicationJar" : "log-clustering-train-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
  "conf" : {
    "spark.driver.memory" : "3gb",
    "spark.executor.memory" : "9gb",
    "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst" : "true",
    "spark.cores.max": "8"
  },
  "schedule" : {
    "period" : "10",
    "timeUnit" : "hours",
    "timeoutPeriodSeconds" : "10800"
  }
}
```

And I want to change 4 values inside it:

"spark.driver.memory" : "1gb",

"spark.executor.memory" : "1gb",

"spark.cores.max" :"1"

"period" : "15",

So the output will be:

```
  {
      "useCaseName" : "rca",
      "algorithm" : "log-clustering-train",
      "mainClass" : "com.hp.analytics.logclustering.MainTrainer",
      "applicationJar" : "log-clustering-train-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
      "conf" : {
        "spark.driver.memory" : "1gb",
        "spark.executor.memory" : "1gb",
        "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst" : "true",
        "spark.cores.max": "1"
      },
      "schedule" : {
        "period" : "15",
        "timeUnit" : "hours",
        "timeoutPeriodSeconds" : "10800"
      }
    }
```

Comment: well if `sed` can solve this, try it out... a simple example is `seq 4 | sed 's/2/two/; s/4/four/'`

Comment: If you don't know how to do it with sed then maybe that's not the simplest option.

Comment: Adding `jq` to your container doesn't seem like a big deal to me, and the solution using `jq` would be much easier to read and robust.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For sed use the following

```
sed -i '/spark.driver.memory/c\   \"spark.driver.memory\" : \"1gb\",' file.txt
sed -i '/spark.executor.memory/c\   \"spark.executor.memory\" : \"1gb\",' file.txt
sed -i '/spark.cores.max/c\   \"spark.cores.max\" : \"1\",' file.txt
sed -i '/period/c\   \"period\" : \"15\",' file.txt
```

Comment: This could be done in a single sed, I have added EDIT into my solution too now.

Answer (score 5):

For that time when you'll be ready for a proper solution using `jq` tool:

```
jq '.conf |= . + {"spark.driver.memory":"1gb","spark.executor.memory":"1gb","spark.cores.max":"1"} | .schedule |= . + {period:"15"}' file
```

The output:

```
{
  "useCaseName": "rca",
  "algorithm": "log-clustering-train",
  "mainClass": "com.hp.analytics.logclustering.MainTrainer",
  "applicationJar": "log-clustering-train-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
  "conf": {
    "spark.driver.memory": "1gb",
    "spark.executor.memory": "1gb",
    "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst": "true",
    "spark.cores.max": "1"
  },
  "schedule": {
    "period": "15",
    "timeUnit": "hours",
    "timeoutPeriodSeconds": "10800"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below will work for both mac and linux.

If you want to read from some variable name value, use first command
and if you have direct value, use second command.

```
sed -ie 's/"key1": .*"/"key1": '\"${value}\"'/g' filename
sed -ie 's/"key1": .*"/"key1": '\"yourvalue\"'/g' filename
```

Comment: Worked like a gem, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

try following awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{
        match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/);
        val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
     }
        /spark.driver.memory/ || /spark.executor.memory/{
        sub(/[0-9]+/,"1",$3);
                                                        }
        /spark.cores.max/{
        sub(/[0-9]+/,"1",$2)
                         }
        /period/{
        sub(/[0-9]+/,"15",$3)
                }
     {
        printf("%s%s\n",!/^ +/?val:"",$0)
     }
    '    Input_file
```

If you want to save the output of this into same Input_file, then you could save above code's output into a temp file and then save it to Input_file again.

***EDIT1:*** a sed solution too now.

```
sed 's/"spark.driver.memory" : "[0-9]gb"/"spark.driver.memory" : "1gb"/;s/"spark.executor.memory" : "[0-9]gb"/"spark.executor.memory" : "1gb"/;s/"spark.cores.max": "[0-9]"/"spark.cores.max" :"1"/;s/"period" : "[0-9]*"/"period" : "15"/'   Input_file
```

If happy with above code's result then use sed -i option to save into the Input_file then.