# How to replace a JSON value with variable using sed, but without forward slash delimiter?

Tags: json, linux, bash, sed

I'm attempting to use the linux command `sed` to dynamically replace the value of the "branch" property. But, here is the kicker.. I'm using a bash environment variable as the value.

The environment variable:

```
export BRANCH_NAME=release/feature-branch
```

Here is my json:

```
{
 "settings": {
   "repo": "myrepo/my-service",
   "branch": "feature/addition-1"
 }
}
```

How do I use sed to transform the JSON into:

```
{
 "settings": {
   "repo": "myrepo/my-service",
   "branch": "release/feature-branch"
 }
}
```

### What I've Tried so far

I have tried [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192835/need-to-change-values-of-json-file-using-sed) example from stackoverflow with several variations, but was unsuccessful with this:

```
sed -i '/branch/c\   \"branch\" : "${BRANCH_NAME}"' settings.json
```

The result was:

```
{
 "settings": {
   "repo": "myrepo/my-service",
   "branch": "${BRANCH_NAME}"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option is to use something that knows how to read and write JSON syntax. The canonical tool is `jq`. Assuming that we have set the shell variable `$BRANCH_NAME`, we do something like this:

```
$ jq --arg branch_name "$BRANCH_NAME" \
  '.settings.branch = $branch_name' settings.json
{
  "settings": {
    "repo": "myrepo/my-service",
    "branch": "release/feature-branch"
  }
}
```

---

The problem with this `sed` command:

```
sed -i '/branch/c\   \"branch\" : "${BRANCH_NAME}"' settings.json
```

is that single quotes (`'`) inhibit variable expansion. You could do this instead:

```
sed -i '/branch/c\   \"branch\" : "'"${BRANCH_NAME}"'"' settings.json
```

Notice the somewhat complex quoting going on there; we have effectively:

```
'...something in single quotes'...something outside single quotes...'something inside single quotes...'
```

More specifically:

- `'/branch/c\   \"branch\" : "'`
- `"${BRANCH_NAME}"`
- `'"'`

This way, the expression `"${BRANCH_NAME}"` is outside of the single quotes and is expanded by the shell.

Demo:

```
$ sed  '/branch/c\   \"branch\" : "'"${BRANCH_NAME}"'"' settings.json
{
 "settings": {
   "repo": "myrepo/my-service",
   "branch": "release/feature-branch"
 }
}
```

Comment: The jq command is easy, but it falls outside of my requirements. The sed command you gave works perfectly! Much thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use sed on JSON data, use a JSON-specific tool:

```bash
jq --arg branch "$BRANCH_NAME" '.settings.branch = $branch' settings.json > tmpfile \
&& mv tmpfile settings.json
```

Comment: OP: Don't use sed on anything that is formatted data, which is not just JSON, but also CSV and XML and HTML. There are already tools that do the right job for you.